# Oracle PLSQL truncate datetimes to 15 min blocks

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, plsql, truncate

I would like to aggregate my data into 15 minute segments (*quarters of the hour*). To do this, I have written some code that generates 15 minute datetime blocks.

```
SELECT 
   TRUNC(SYSDATE,'hh') + 0.25/24 - (ROWNUM) *0.25/ 24
   AS time_start,
   ROWNUM,
   TRUNC(SYSDATE,'hh') + 0.25/24 - (ROWNUM - 1) *0.25/ 24
   AS time_end
FROM widsys.consist 
WHERE ROWNUM <3000
ORDER BY sysdate
```

The problem with my code is because it uses an hour truncation, it will only generate time stamps from the beginning of the most recent hour. For example, it is `11:49AM` now so the first stamp generated is `11:00AM.`

I need it to generate stamps from the beginning of the last 15 minute block (`11:45AM` from the example above). Can anyone please help me?

Comment: See the *correct answer* [here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1008150?start=0&tstart=0) and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Its only sql, not pl/sql

Answer (score 9):

This will get you the nearest quarter.

```
select sysdate,
       trunc(sysdate,'mi') -                           --truncate to the nearest minute
       numtodsinterval(                                --convert the minutes in number to interval type and subtract.
                       mod(to_char(sysdate,'mi'),15),  --find the minutes from the nearest quarter
                      'minute'                          
                      ) as nearest_quarter
  from dual;
```

Output:

```
sysdate                             nearest_quarter
-----------------------------------------------------------------
October, 11 2013 05:54:24+0000      October, 11 2013 05:45:00+0000
October, 11 2013 05:22:24+0000      October, 11 2013 05:15:00+0000
```

Use this as your starting value and then iterate over this.

```
with cte as(
  select trunc(sysdate,'mi') - 
         numtodsinterval(mod(to_char(sysdate,'mi'),15),'minute') as nearest_quarter
  from dual
  )
select nearest_quarter - numtodsinterval((level - 1)*15, 'minute'),
       nearest_quarter - numtodsinterval((level - 2)*15, 'minute')
from cte
connect by level <= 10;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/18478).

Answer (score 3):

Another with width_bucket:

```
SELECT trunc(SYSDATE, 'hh')+ (width_bucket(to_number(to_char(SYSDATE, 'mi')), 0 , 60, 4)-1)*15/(24*60) x
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH24') + FLOOR((TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MI') - trunc(sysdate,'HH24'))*1440/:mi)*:mi/1440 FROM DUAL
```