# Oracle categorizing the timestamp column into 15 minute bucket

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on writing a SQL query to categorize one of my timestamp column to 15 minutes bucket. I did some research and tried multiple methods but I am not getting the desired result.

```
SELECT
dd,
trunc(dd) + ROUND(TO_CHAR(dd,'SS')/900)/96 as round_1,
trunc(dd, 'hh24') + ROUND(to_char(dd, 'MI')/15)*15/1440 as round_2,
trunc(dd, 'mi') - mod(EXTRACT(minute FROM cast(dd as timestamp)), 15) / (24 * 60) as round_3,
to_char(trunc(dd,'hh') + (15*round(to_char(trunc(dd,'MI'),'MI')/15))/1440,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as round_4
FROM
Table
```

When I execute the above queries, I see the following results.

[image]

The expected result is
[image]

***Edits, Updated the Question based on Gordon reply

Comment: This would be a generic function to achieve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58518246/how-can-we-get-the-15-minutes-time-interval/58519424#58519424

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TRUNC()` function for each addend of the below addition as an option :

```
SELECT dd,
       TRUNC(dd,'HH24')+
       TRUNC(TO_CHAR(dd,'MI')/15)*INTERVAL '15' MINUTE
  FROM tab
```

The <kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ebde4360e3daa96bd73c3a4a058be53c)</kbd> in order to display the result through `TO_CHAR()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't have a `datetime` data type.  If the column is a timestamp (as your code suggests), then you can use this logic:

```
select trunc(current_timestamp, 'HH24') + floor(extract(minute from current_timestamp) / 4) * interval '15' minute
from dual
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as you mentioned above, yes it is a Timestamp column and I executed you suggested query and this is the out I am getting. I am not sure why 5:53 is converted to 8:15 instead of 5:45.
(2020-10-03 05:53:14   | 2020-10-03 08:15:00),
(2020-10-05 05:46:05   | 2020-10-05 07:45:00),
(2020-10-10 00:05:33   | 2020-10-10 00:15:00),
(2020-10-11 06:48:29   | 2020-10-11 09:00:00),
(2020-10-13 00:05:04   | 2020-10-13 00:15:00),
(2020-09-20 07:12:12   | 2020-09-20 07:45:00),
(2020-10-01 12:17:20   | 2020-10-01 13:00:00),
(2020-10-09 00:03:58   | 2020-10-09 00:00:00)

Comment: @Nik . . . You need to use. your actual column instead of `current_timestamp`.

Comment: Yes I used the acutal col, I used the following statement
trunc(dd, 'HH24') + floor(extract(minute from dd) / 4) * interval '15' minute . If you see in my previous comment the dates are same but time is changing.